# LINQ GroupBy return List as result

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List containing Transaction objects. What I am trying to do is find the transactions in said List that have the same transaction.Buyer.UserID and group them together into a List of Lists.

Each Sub-List item will contain multiple transaction objects where the transaction.Buyer.UserID is the same.

What I have so far is:

```
            var _ordersToCombine = 
            _transactions.GroupBy(transaction => transaction.Buyer.UserID).Select(transaction => transaction);
```

What I have coming in:

```
List<Transaction>:
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User1" ...}
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User2" ...}
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User1" ...}
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User3" ...}
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User4" ...}
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User3" ...}
```

What I expect it to return is:

```
List<List<Transaction>>:
    List<Transaction>:
        Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User1" ...}
        Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User1" ...}
    List<Transaction>:
        Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User3" ...}
        Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User3" ...}
```

...And also delete these Transactions from the main list, so in this example the main list would then look like:

```
List<Transaction>:
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User2" ...}
    Transaction { Buyer.UserID = "User4" ...}
```

Linq is a new concept for me that I am trying to get my head around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: I posted an answer which I think provides what you need, good luck.

Comment: I have edited the question to try and better explain the scenario

Comment: It's basically the same solution with a minor modification, see my edit

Comment: LINQ is for *querying*, not *modifying*, so you can't (or shouldn't) use it to modify your original list like in your last code example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use this for grouping:

```
var results = transactions
.GroupBy(p => p.Buyer.UserID)
.Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
.Select(x=> new List<Transaction>(x));
```

This should produce your `List<List<Transaction>` with repeated users from the main list. 
LINQ is not really the right tool to modify a collection while iterating over it. If you really need it, do:

```
var results = transactions.ToList()
.GroupBy(p => p.Buyer.UserID)
.Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
.Select(x=> 
{
    foreach(var item in x)
        transactions.Remove(item);
    return new List<Transaction>(x);
});
```

Notice that a copy of transactions list is made to execute the query on ( `transactions.ToList()` and remove operations are made on the original list. Hope that helped.

Comment: I selected this as the correct answer since it solved my exact problem, however the other answers are just as good for similar scenarios.

Comment: Just what I needed...well, almost :P

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
var dic = _transactions.GroupBy(t => t.Buyer.UserID).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.ToList());
```

GroupBy returns a

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>
```

Each IGrouping<> contains as Key, the group criteria, and each IGrouping is enumerable (you list the grouped values)

Since, the question change :

Don't create anonymous types in the GroupBy delegates (no new {...})
Instead, directly target the property (because internally, GroupBy uses equality to group things, and since you create a new anonymous object, there will be nothing grouped, since each new object is a different one)

```
.GroupBy(o => o.Buyer.UserID, o.ToList)
```

Moreover,

```
Select(p => p)
```

does nothing, it's an identity function. It's useless.

If what you want is a List of List, I think you can directly use a Dictionary. (see the first part of my answer) You can enumerate a dictionary in the same way you enumerate a List. And add/remove/replace items in it.

The Dictionary returned will be of type :

```
Dictionary<int,List<Transactions>> dic =....
```

With Key = UserId, and for each key, a List of transactions.
Moreover, it's really faster than a List of List, since you can directly access the transactions :

```
int userId = 42;
List<Transactions> transactions = dic[userId];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I think I didn't explain the scenario very well.. I have updated the question.

Comment: I expanded my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

[Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq).

This has answer to your query.

```
var results = transactions.GroupBy(p => p.Buyer.UserID,
                         (key, g) => new { UserID = key, Cars = g.ToList() });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I think I didn't explain the scenario very well.. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly,

You have a transaction list,
and a transaction list of lists.

You need to group the latter,
by the userId, where the value will be the transactions that correspond to that user.

If that's the case,
I prepared a small sample that may help.

good luck

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Buyer Buyer { get; set; }
}

public class Buyer
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}


[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{

    var t1 = new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 1 } };
    var t2 = new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 2 } };
    var t3 = new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 3 } };
    var t4 = new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 1 } };
    var t5 = new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 3 } };

    var tList1 = new List<Transaction> { t1, t2, t3 };
    var tList2 = new List<Transaction> { t4, t5 };

    var tLists = new List<List<Transaction>> { tList1 , tList2};

    var result = tLists.
        SelectMany(o => o).
        GroupBy(o =>  new 
        {
            UserId = o.Buyer.UserID
        },
        (key, items) => new
        {
            UserId = key.UserId,
            Transactions = items.Select(p => p).ToList()
        }).
        ToList();
}
```

This is an updated solution to the edit by the author:

```
    var transactions = new List<Transaction>
    {
        new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 1 } },
        new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 2 } },
        new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 3 } },
        new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 1 } },
        new Transaction { Buyer = new Buyer { UserID = 3 } }
    };

    var result = transactions.
        Select(o => o).
        GroupBy(o => new
        {
            UserId = o.Buyer.UserID
        },
        (key, items) => new
        {
            //UserId = key.UserId,
            Transactions = items.Select(p => p).ToList()
        }).
        ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I think I didn't explain the scenario very well.. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

No you are getting an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` See: [MSDN Group By](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.90).aspx)

So basically it returns a list of groups. The group contains the key where it is grouped on and the element which is the list of items which belongs to the group

The List

- Group 1

  - Group Key
  - Items (list of your objects)
- Group 2

  - Group Key
  - Items (list of your objects)

Nice explanation: https://www.udemy.com/blog/linq-group-by/